# Azure Databricks BulkMoveToSql Date/Time Conversion Issue

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I have a Spark / Databricks job that moves data from the data bricks file system (AVRO files) into an Azure SQL database. Doing this with JDBC works fine (read the data frame from file storage, write it to a JDBC target), but is a little slow.

Microsoft provides a SQLDB Spark driver that has a bulk copy function. If I use this driver and invoke the .write() method, everything works as expected:

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).sqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)

However, if I use the bulk copy:

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)

it appears that the driver does not handle date fields properly:

om.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've validated that the data frame schema and the table metadata are "correct" or at least as expected; the table layout that the .write() method creates chooses the Azure SQL datetime field for date values, so I used this same structure when prepping the table for the bulkCopy (.write() will create a table, .bulkCopyToSqlDB seems to want the table to already exist).

Any ideas on how to get the bulkCopy to interpret / convert the dates correctly? Do I need to convert them to strings in the dataframe in a different format first?